# How to track progress of request submitted to the server via jQuery (ajax)?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have some PHP app. At the moment I am developing part where an user submits a request/form to the server via ajax (jQuery). Server will insert thousands of records in MySQL database that will probably take couple minutes (due to various calculations etc).

Question: Is there a way to track progress of updates on server side? I understand I can write some output once everything is finished. A workaround would be something like:
- store somewhere session ID plus progress details (example: processed 3k inserts out of 5k - maybe in some progress table in database
- have front end jQuery script requesting that information from the server every 10 seconds or so...

Any ideas? Please feel free to ask any question you may have. Thank you.

Comment: Your idea is pretty much the only way to do this. The progress event of the XHR will only track the status of the file as it's uploaded, not any work being done on the server as a result of the request

Comment: @Rory McCrossan That is what I thought. Will work on it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

While I don't know the specifics of what you're doing server-side, a script that takes a "couple minutes" to execute likely involves several distinct steps. It might make sense to have the script execute one step at a time, return its result, and then get called again to execute the next step.

By using a process like this, you'll be able to track progress client-side. The caveat is that if the client closes the browser window or leaves the page with your ajax code, the remaining steps won't be executed.

Comment: Essentially there are few selects plus additional math calculations. For each select additional couple records are being inserted. It has to be a stored procedure otherwise it could result in partially complete process. Thanks.

Comment: If you wanted to do it the way I suggest, you'd write to temp tables and only copy to the live table in the last step.

Comment: Actually, I think I will have my stored procedure to write down progress (example: every 1k records or so) of a percentage in some table while executing. And from my front-end I could retrieve that number every while to display progress bar ...

Thanks.